# Android: sumsung android 6.0.1 version notification not show

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

My code:

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle(data.get("TITLE"))
                        .setContentText(data.get("TEXT"))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setLargeIcon(icon)
                        .setSmallIcon(icon1);

Uri idUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
notificationBuilder.setSound(idUri);

final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification note = notificationBuilder.build();
notificationManager.notify(1, note);
```

In another versions and devices, it works fine

But in this version receive notification but not show to the user.

Comment: where does `note` variable come from? It should be the `notificationBuilder.build()` onto that.

Comment: Debug your Code, i think your Code throws Exception somewhere in 6.0.1

Comment: @dr3k i change my code, sorry

Comment: @AniruddhParihar how can i ?

Comment: enable debugger from Android Studio and put debug point at line : .setContentTitle(data.get("TITLE")) and execute your code line by line by pressing F6.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar i not found error. notification receive fine, but not show to user